# CORS request 405 status code

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, http-status-code-502

Hello everyone please help me about my CORS problem 
Im creating an API request from another domain my code below with an error,

```
 var headers = {
        host: host,
        path: url + instance + '?action=reset',
        method: 'POST'
    };


var request = https.request(headers, function (response) {
    logger('OCICompute', 'reset', 'INSTANCE', 'Got response from OPCAPI:' + response.statusCode);

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"); 
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT");
        res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With"); 


    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        response.on('data', function (body) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.json(data);
        });
    } else {
        logger('OCICompute', 'reset', 'ERROR', 'stop fail');
        res.json({'result': 'Fail'});
    }
});
```

code above is on my module

and I have option in my main.

```
app.opts('/\.*/', function(req, res, next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With");
res.send(200);
```

});

When I access this rest im getting this 
405 error method not accepted and only got this

```
Host: api Url
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:3000/?root=compute
Authorization: Bearer Token
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive

Allow: OPTIONS
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 24 Apr 2018 02:05:47 GMT
Server: LBAAS
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

I have another code which do exactly what I expected, the only difference is im using GET method. Above with error is POST.

```
 var headers = {
    host: host,
    path: url + instance + '?action=reset',
    method: **'GET'**
};
```

And here is the result

>

```
 Host: api Url User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0)
> Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0 Accept: */* Accept-Language:
> ja,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Referer:
> http://localhost:3000/?root=compute Authorization: Bearer Token
> Origin: http://localhost:3000 Connection: keep-alive
> 
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
> Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Accept,
> X-Requested-With Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 2556
> Content-Type: application/json Date: Tue, 24 Apr 2018 02:05:57 GMT
> Server: LBAAS Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
> includeSubdomains; X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection:
> 1; mode=block
```

Here is my code on client side

```
self.stopButtonClick = function (event) {
                    console.log("停止ボタンが押されました");
var headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + self.ociComputeToken._latestValue};              

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "GET",
                        async: true,
                        headers: headers
                    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (data.result !== 'Fail') {
                            self.compartmentHandler(self.compartmentId());
                        } else {
                            self.stopButtonClick(event);
                        }
                    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('サービスエラー');
                        self.stopButtonClick(event);
                    });
                };
```

Comment: Use `app.post` instead of 'app.opts' , and set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` at server only, there is no need to set at client code. The value 'http://localhost:3000' should be domain of client not server. if frontend is on port 80 and server on 3000,  user `http://localhost:80`

Comment: Why im getting Allow: OPTIONS instead of Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
> Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Accept,

Comment: The data you posted is RAW data i guess, due to which everything is getting scrumbled.

Comment: I include my code in the client side

Answer (score 0):

I just solve this one, and the problem is the url that im accessing is not correct, But then I got another error which is 502 bad gateway, GET is working fine, but what should I do when POST method is use?

Comment: Please don't use the Answer section to ask a new question. It appears as though this question was solved due to a typo, so close or delete it. Ask a new question for your new question.